# Show the monotonicity of the following expectation.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis

Now, there is an expectation as $$E\left[(1-a\cdot b^{X})^{m}\right]$$ where $m\in \mathbb{N}$ ,$a\in (0,1]$ and $b \in(0,1]$ are constants. $X\sim B(n-1,p)$ is a binomial random variable. I am not sure whether this expectation increases as $n$ and $p$ increases. If so, how can I prove it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ and/or $p$ increases, $X$ increases stochastically. This means that if $n_1\leqslant n_2$ and $p_1\leqslant p_2$, there exists $X_1$ with $B(n_1-1,p_1)$ distribution and $X_2$ with $B(n_2-1,p_2)$ distribution such that $X_1\leqslant X_2$ almost surely. Furthermore, as soon as $(n_1,p_1)\ne(n_2,p_2)$, $X_1\lt X_2$ with positive probability. Since the function $x\mapsto(1-ab^x)^m$ is increasing, this fact yields the result.

Comment: Thanks,Didder. Does $X_1<X_2$ mean that $P(X_1>k)<P(X_2>k)$?

Comment: *Implies*, yes.